# What kinds of data in a device driver can be shared among processes?

Tags: c, concurrency, linux-device-driver, semaphore

In device drivers, how can we tell what data is shared among processes and what is local to a process? The [Linux Device Drivers book](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf) mentions

> Any time that a hardware or software resource is shared beyond a single thread of execution, and the possibility exists that one thread could encounter an inconsistent view of that resource, you must explicitly manage access to that resource.

But what kinds of software resources can be shared among threads and what kinds of data *cannot* be shared? I know that global variables are generally considered as shared memory but what other kinds of things need to be protected?

For example, is the `struct inode` and `struct file` types passed in file operations like `open`, `release`, `read`, `write`, etc. considered to be shared?
In the `open` call inside [main.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/source/2.6.25/ldd-examples/scull/main.c) , why is `dev` (in the line `dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_dev, cdev);`) not protected with a lock if it points to a `struct scull_dev` entry in the global array `scull_devices`?
In `scull_write`, why isn't the line `int quantum = dev->quantum, qset = dev->qset;` locked with a semaphore since it's accessing a global variable?

```
/* In scull.h */

struct scull_qset {
    void **data;   /* pointer to an array of pointers which each point to a quantum buffer */
    struct scull_qset *next;
};

struct scull_dev {
    struct scull_qset *data;  /* Pointer to first quantum set */
    int quantum;              /* the current quantum size */
    int qset;                 /* the current array size */
    unsigned long size;       /* amount of data stored here */
    unsigned int access_key;  /* used by sculluid and scullpriv */
    struct semaphore sem;     /* mutual exclusion semaphore */
    struct cdev cdev;        /* Char device structure */
};



/* In main.c */

struct scull_dev *scull_devices;    /* allocated in scull_init_module */
int scull_major = SCULL_MAJOR;
int scull_minor = 0;
int scull_nr_devs = SCULL_NR_DEVS;
int scull_quantum = SCULL_QUANTUM;
int scull_qset = SCULL_QSET;


ssize_t scull_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count,
                loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct scull_dev *dev = filp->private_data;  /*  flip->private_data assigned in scull_open */
    struct scull_qset *dptr;
    int quantum = dev->quantum, qset = dev->qset;
    int itemsize = quantum * qset;
    int item;    /* item in linked list */
    int s_pos;    /* position in qset data array */
    int q_pos;    /* position in quantum */
    int rest;
    ssize_t retval = -ENOMEM; /* value used in "goto out" statements */

    if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    /* find listitem, qset index and offset in the quantum */
    item = (long)*f_pos / itemsize;
    rest = (long)*f_pos % itemsize;
    s_pos = rest / quantum;
    q_pos = rest % quantum;

    /* follow the list up to the right position */
    dptr = scull_follow(dev, item);
    if (dptr == NULL)
        goto out;
    if (!dptr->data) {
        dptr->data = kmalloc(qset * sizeof(char *), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!dptr->data)
            goto out;
        memset(dptr->data, 0, qset * sizeof(char *));
    }
    if (!dptr->data[s_pos]) {
        dptr->data[s_pos] = kmalloc(quantum, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!dptr->data[s_pos])
            goto out;
    }
    /* write only up to the end of this quantum */
    if (count > quantum - q_pos)
        count = quantum - q_pos;

    if (copy_from_user(dptr->data[s_pos]+q_pos, buf, count)) {
        retval = -EFAULT;
        goto out;
    }
    *f_pos += count;
    retval = count;

        /* update the size */
    if (dev->size < *f_pos)
        dev->size = *f_pos;

  out:
    up(&dev->sem);
    return retval;
}


int scull_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    struct scull_dev *dev; /* device information */

    /* Question: Why was the lock not placed here? */

    dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_dev, cdev);
    filp->private_data = dev; /* for other methods */

    /* now trim to 0 the length of the device if open was write-only */
    if ( (filp->f_flags & O_ACCMODE) == O_WRONLY) {
        if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
            return -ERESTARTSYS;
        scull_trim(dev); /* ignore errors */
        up(&dev->sem);
    }
    return 0;          /* success */
}


int scull_init_module(void)
{
    int result, i;
    dev_t dev = 0;

    /* assigns major and minor numbers (left out for brevity) */


    /* 
     * allocate the devices -- we can't have them static, as the number
     * can be specified at load time
     */
    scull_devices = kmalloc(scull_nr_devs * sizeof(struct scull_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!scull_devices) {
        result = -ENOMEM;
        goto fail;  /* isn't this redundant? */
    }
    memset(scull_devices, 0, scull_nr_devs * sizeof(struct scull_dev));

    /* Initialize each device. */
    for (i = 0; i < scull_nr_devs; i++) {
        scull_devices[i].quantum = scull_quantum;
        scull_devices[i].qset = scull_qset;
        init_MUTEX(&scull_devices[i].sem);
        scull_setup_cdev(&scull_devices[i], i); 
    }

    /* some other stuff (left out for brevity) */
    return 0; /* succeed */

  fail:         
    scull_cleanup_module();  /* left out for brevity */
    return result;
}


/*
 * Set up the char_dev structure for this device.
 */
static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev, int index)
{
    int err, devno = MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor + index);

    cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);
    dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops;  /* isn't this redundant? */
    err = cdev_add (&dev->cdev, devno, 1);
    /* Fail gracefully if need be */
    if (err)
        printk(KERN_NOTICE "Error %d adding scull%d", err, index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All data in memory can be considered a "shared resource" if both threads are able to access it*. The only resource they wouldn't be shared between processors is the data in the registers, which is abstracted away in C.

There are two reasons that you would not practically consider two resources to be shared (even though they do not *actually* mean that two threads could not theoretically access them, some nightmarish code could sometimes bypass these).

1. Only one thread can/does access it. Clearly if only one thread accesses a variable then there can be no race conditions. This is the reason local variables and single threaded programs do not need locking mechanisms.
2. The value is constant. You can't get different results based on order of access if the value can never change.

The program you have shown here is incomplete, so it is hard to say, but each of the variables accessed without locking must meet one of the criteria for this program to be thread safe.

There are some non-obvious ways to meet the criteria, such as if a variable is constant or limited to one thread only in a specific context.

You gave two examples of lines that were not locked. For the first line.

```
dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_dev, cdev);
```

This line does not actually access any variables, it just computes where the struct containing `cdev` would be. There can be no race conditions because nobody else has access to your pointers (though they have access to what they point to), they are only accessible within the function (this is not true of what they point to). This meets criteria (1).

The other example is

```
int quantum = dev->quantum, qset = dev->qset;
```

This one is a bit harder to say without context, but my best guess is that it is assumed that `dev->quantum` and `dev->qset` will never change during the function call. This seems supported by the fact that they are only called in `scull_init_module` which should only be called once at the very beginning. I believe this fits criteria (2).

Which brings up another way that you might change a shared variable without locking, if you know that other threads will not try to access it until you are done for some other reason (eg they are not extant yet)

In short, all memory is shared, but sometimes you can get away with acting like its not.

---

*There are embedded systems where each processor has some amount of RAM that only it could use, but this is not the typical case.

Comment: I didn't add it to the code sample because it would become too long, but in the [main.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/source/2.6.25/ldd-examples/scull/main.c) in `scull_ioctl` there is a line that modifies `scull_quantum` (which is a global variable). `scull_trim` in turn sets `dev->quantum` to whatever `scull_quantum` is. Couldn't the combination of those two cause a race condition?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but `scull_trim` only seems to be called in `scull_open` and `scull_cleanup_module`. If those will never be called while `scull_write` is called there would be no conflict. I don't even see anywhere where `scull_open` is called, so it is hard to say. Either way the code seems to be playing with fire, even if it is thread safe.

Comment: How can I tell if multiple threads can access a piece of data? Is there a list of types of data that can/cannot be accessed by multiple threads? Why can't local variables be accessible between threads?

Comment: There isn't a silver bullet to determine if multiple threads can access a piece of data. You have to analyze to see if there is a chance of concurrent access. For local variables, each thread has its own stack, so unless they store pointers to their variables in a variable the other thread has access to (e.g. a global) there is no way for the other thread to access it. There is no restriction on what data types can be shared.

Comment: Is heap space shared too?

Comment: @JakeKing yes, in fact usually shared resources are on the heap since they stick around until explicitly deallocated, (unlike stack variables which are gone when the function exits).

Comment: also, this link (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch03s03.html) seems to indicate that `open` is in fact called at the very beginning, before other functions, so would not be run concurrently with `scull_write`. It does not say it explicitly, so I wouldn't bank on it unless you find documentation that guarantees it.